# ExcelJS - force formula bar to have same precision as cells

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devextreme, exceljs

I have been using ExcelJs (in conjunction with DevExtreme DataGrid component) in my project for a long time. Recently I updated to ExcelJS 4.3.0 and a weird issue began to occur.

I am using ExcelJS to create an spreadsheet from a datagrid. Previously in the generated excel file, the precision in the formula bar was identical to the precision in the cells.

Since I upgraded this appears to have changed. Now, the formula bar seems to include the full precision of the value, while the cells show the precision I want. For example, the cell shows "3.15" but when I click the cell, the formula bar shows "3.154". We are also formatting the value to have comma separators but this formatting is also lost from the formula bar when the cell is selected, e.g. the cell value "1,000.99" becomes "1000.99" in the formula bar.

I am using a function to add some formatting when the table is exported to excel, the function looks like this:

```
public formatCellsForExport(cell: any): void {
  if (cell.gridCell.rowType === 'data') {

    if (typeof cell.gridCell.column.format === 'function') {
      // if column has a formatter use it
      const formatted = cell.gridCell.column.format(cell.gridCell.value);

      if (formatted) {
        // try to determine format from formatted value
        if (formatted.includes(',')) {
          cell.excelCell.numFmt = '#,##0.00';
        } else if (!formatted.includes(',') && formatted.includes('.')) {
          cell.excelCell.numFmt = '0.00';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works, it just needs extending to force the formula bar to have the same precision as the cells.

I've tried to set the type of the cells, e.g. to `RichText`, like this:

`cell.excelCell.type = ValueType.RichText;`

But this threw an error that the `type` property only has a getter.

I've also tried forcing the cell value to be a string after adding the `numFmt` in the above code, like this:

`cell.excelCell.value = cell.excelCell.value.toString();`

This sort of works in that the formula bar displays the exact same value as the cells, but it breaks the formatting displayed in the cells, so where I want e.g. "1,000.99" the cell (and formula bar) displays 1000.99

**Edit**

I've made some progress and managed to align most of the cell/formula bar values. I've changed the above function to handle formatting to this now:

```
public formatCellsForExport(cell: any): void {
  if (typeof cell.gridCell.column.format === 'function') {
    // if column has a formatter use it
    const formatted = cell.gridCell.column.format(cell.gridCell.value);

    if (formatted) {
      cell.excelCell.value = formatted;
    }
  }

  if (cell.gridCell.column.displayFormatString === 'percent') {
    cell.excelCell.numFmt = '#,##0.00%';
  }
}
```

Now almost all cell values look identical in the formula bar, the only issue is that it only works for cells that have a format function Some cell values like percentages don't have a format function, so now it is only percent-based cells with the issue - the cells display, e.g. 1,000.00% but the formula bar displays 1000%

Comment: formatting is one thing, input value another, maybe assign the value manually in the desired format.. but it's just guessing, I think you'll need to provide some reproducible example to get help, for example, input value and formula that assigns value to the cell

Comment: Thanks @traynor, I have actually tried this (edited my question to reflect that) but it doesn't help. I'm not sure I can provide a full reproducible example - this is a tiny part of an enormous production application. This is also behaviour which seems to have changed between versions of ExcelJS but which isn't really covered in the documentation/migration guide

Comment: wait, are you using devextreme datagrid?

Comment: Yes, we are using latest version of DevExtreme datagrid, in fact it was updating this to DX v 23 which forced us to upgrade to latest ExcelJS

Comment: well, that's an important information, you should include that information (your last comment, for example), and add corresponding tag

Comment: also, I wouldn't put it all on exceljs, i.e. rule out the framework and other dependencies causing the issue

Comment: Good point, I've updated the description and tags, thanks